# How to convert an object of objects to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an external file **people.json**. How I can convert it to a javascript array with json syntax?
this is the **people.json** content:

```
{
"1":{
    "Name":"Jhon",
    "Surname":"Kenneth",
    "mobile":329129293,
    "email":"jhon@gmail.com"
},
"2":{
    "Name":"Thor",
    "Surname":"zvalk",
    "mobile":349229293,
    "email":"thor@gmail.com"
},
"3":{
    "Name":"Mila",
    "Surname":"Kvuls",
    "mobile":329121293,
    "email":"mila@gmail.com"
}
}
```

I want an array with this format

```
var person = [
{ "name":"jhon" , "surname":"kenneth", "mobile":329129293, "email":"jhon@gmail.com"}, 
{ "Name":"Thor", "Surname":"zvalk", "mobile":349229293, "email":"thor@gmail.com" }, 
{ "Name":"Mila", "Surname":"Kvuls", "mobile":329121293, "email":"mila@gmail.com"}
];
```

I tried with the next code, but it doesnt worker:

```
 var person;   
$.getJSON('people.json', function (json) {
person[]= json
});
```

By the way, the file contacts.json is in my server.

Comment: That pretty much is an "array" in JSON format. By the looks of the code you have added, you need to include jQuery.

Comment: @SEoF it is an array, but it contains something different than desired.

Comment: yeah, it already had jquery include

Comment: Well, the rows inside the case of the keys in the array are inconsistent. It looks like he just wants it to be an array instead of an object, and at which point, I find myself questioning why.

Comment: `javascript “array” in JSON format?` sounds weird. After the JSON is parsed, you have an object of objects, which you want to convert to an array of objects. That's all. JSON is just the format you encoded your data in.

Comment: @SEoF could be numerous reasons why such as passin the data into a plugin that expects a particular format. Agree that can likely change server code that is creating data and solve problem also

Comment: i want an javascript array, because the I want to add new items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function (json) {
    var people = [];
    for (var key in json) {
        if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var item = json[key];
            people.push({
                name: item.Name,
                surname: item.Surname,
                mobile: item.mobile,
                email: item.email
            });            
        }
    }

    // at this stage the people object will contain the desired output
});
```

Comment: hey, and how could I show the people array content in a div ??

Comment: Easily, you could use the `.text()` function: `$('#divId').text(JSON.stringify(people));`. And if you wanted to show for example the Surname of the second person you could directly access it: `$('#divId').text(people[1].surname);`.

Comment: Why the verbosity? Each `json[key]` already refers to an object. Why not just push that?

Comment: Because javascript is a case-sensitive language. The original array has the `Name` and `Surname` properties (notice the capital letter) whereas in the expected array all property names are lowercase (`name` and `surname`). That's why I perform the mapping - in order to achieve the expected result. Actually the OP has mixed up casing. In the first element of the expected array they are lowercase whereas in the second they have uppercase as well.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Guessing that's a typo. The expected Array only has the lower-cased keys for the first item. The rest use the original case.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I've just noticed that. Probably a typo indeed. If this is the case then the code could be shortened by pushing the `item` variable directly: `people.push(json[key]);`.

Answer (score 4):

Can use  jQuery `$.map()`

```
var newArray=$.map( originalObject, function(item){
    return item;
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qmfn2/

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to fetch the JSON file using an AJAX request. Then iterate through the received JSON object and add each property to an array.

```
function convertToArray (receivedObj) {
    var array = [], key;
    for (key in receivedObj) {
        array.push(receivedObj[key]);
    }
    return array;
}

$.getJSON('people.json', function (json) {
    var array = convertToArray(json);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var array = $.map($.parseJSON(data), Object);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mXFKL/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON('people.json', function (json) {
var array = convertToArray(json);
});
```